# Creating different headers for LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, headers

I am trying to find out how to edit the header of two sections in a LibreOffice document, who apparently somehow have merged to be under just under ONE header.  I want to split the two sections, so I can create a new header for the second part, without affecting the following 10 parts!

I did something similar when I created all the 21 headers for the different chapters in this book, but I cannot remember how I did this!  I do not use columns or anything - just simple page text.  It is as if the drop-down menus all are missing exactly what I need...  The trick I need is how to split a section into two, without disturbing the text, so each part can get it own header.

Answer (score 0):

Each page style uses a different header.  So go to *Insert -> Manual Break -> Page Break* and select a different page style.

Page styles can be managed in the *Styles and Formatting* sidebar.

**EDIT**:

Instructions for creating a new page style are in the online documentation: https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Creating_and_Applying_Page_Styles.

Comment: I have done this, and it does not work.  It forces me to choose the "style of another existing page, and that changes the heading for BOTH the two sections.  I cannot separate them, so changes in one do not affect also the other one.

Comment: And the Styles and Formatting leads to a list of formats that do not include a single one of my choices from Page Break!  Very confusing.  I don't think I understand what the hell a "style" actually is!  I do not know how to create one and how to use it, what purposes it has.

Comment: And the headers for each page is NOT separate!  When I change it on one page, it automatically changes on all the other pages too, in both the two parts I want to split!

Comment: When I go to Page Break, I do get a list of all styles I have used for the 26 chapters in the book, but I cannot ADD one!  I can only change names and select another one - which becomes the same for both the two halves I want to split!  If I can create a new one, I think I can solve the problem - but I do not know how to do that.

Comment: @Mogens Eliasen: It sounds like these issues will all go away by creating a new page style.  For how to do this, see my edited answer.

Comment: Exactly!  Thanks!  The trick is to know how to CREATE a new style!  It takes RIGHT-CLICKING on "New" - who would know that???  This solved the problem completely.  I appreciate your edit.

Comment: Glad to hear it solved the problem.  Please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).